# How to get the width and height of a rectangle drawn by a mouse in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering when I draw a rectangle on a HTML5 canvas using mouse clicks and dragging how I can get the feedback about what the width and height are each time it is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the following code get the x and y coordinates and calculate the width and height.

https://jsfiddle.net/w3tian/Lbz3ayyd/

```
<body>

<h2 onclick="showCoords(event)">
=============================<br>
potential area that contains the rectangle
=============================<br>
</h2>

<p><strong>Hint:</strong> Try to click different places in the heading.
</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function showCoords(event) {
   var x = event.clientX;
   var y = event.clientY;
   var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so : Calculate the start position and size of the rectangle by the mouse coordinates

```
var width = endX - startX;
var height = endY - startY;
```

Please try this demo :

```js
var Paper = can.Control(
    {
        defaults: {
            rect: {
                minWidth: 10,
                minHeight: 10
            }
        }
    },
    {
        /**
         * Initialize
         */
        init: function() {

            // Bind event handlers
            this.element.on('mousedown.paper', $.proxy(this.startDrawRect, this));
        },

        /**
         * Start drawing a rectangle
         *
         * @param   e
         */
        startDrawRect: function(e) {

            // Get canvas offset
            var offset = this.element.offset();
            this.canvasOffsetLeft = offset.left;
            this.canvasOffsetTop = offset.top;

            // Save start positions
            this.drawStartX = e.pageX - this.canvasOffsetLeft;
            this.drawStartY = e.pageY - this.canvasOffsetTop;

            // Create the rectangle
            this.drawingRect = this.createRect(this.drawStartX, this.drawStartY, 0, 0);

            // Bind event handlers
            this.element.on('mousemove.paper', $.proxy(this.drawRect, this));
            this.element.on('mouseup.paper', $.proxy(this.endDrawRect, this));
        },

        /**
         * Draw the rectangle
         *
         * @param   e
         */
        drawRect: function(e) {

            var currentX = e.pageX - this.canvasOffsetLeft;
            var currentY = e.pageY - this.canvasOffsetTop;

            // Calculate the position and size of the rectangle we are drawing
            var position = this.calculateRectPos(this.drawStartX, this.drawStartY, currentX, currentY);

            // Set position and size
            this.drawingRect.css(position);
        },

        /**
         * Finish drawing the rectangle
         *
         * @param   e
         */
        endDrawRect: function(e) {

            var currentX = e.pageX - this.canvasOffsetLeft;
            var currentY = e.pageY - this.canvasOffsetTop;

            // Calculate the position and size of the rectangle we are drawing
            var position = this.calculateRectPos(this.drawStartX, this.drawStartY, currentX, currentY);
console.log("Width :" + position.width);
console.log("Height :" + position.height);
            if (position.width < this.options.rect.minWidth || position.height < this.options.rect.minHeight) {

                // The drawn rectangle is too small, remove it
                this.drawingRect.remove();
            }
            else {

                // Set position and size
                this.drawingRect.css(position);

                // The rectangle is big enough, select it
                this.selectRect(this.drawingRect);
            }

            // Unbind event handlers
            this.element.off('mousemove.paper');
            this.element.off('mouseup.paper');
        },

        /**
         * Create a rectangle
         *
         * @param   x
         * @param   y
         * @param   w
         * @param   h
         */
        createRect: function(x, y, w, h) {

            return $('<div/>').addClass('rect').css({
                left: x,
                top: y,
                width: w,
                height: h
            }).appendTo(this.element);
        },

        /**
         * Select the given rectangle
         *
         * @param   rect
         */
        selectRect: function(rect) {

            // Deselect the previous selected rectangle
            this.selectedRect && this.selectedRect.removeClass('selected');

            // Select the given rectangle
            this.selectedRect = rect;
            this.selectedRect.addClass('selected');
        },

        /**
         * Calculate the start position and size of the rectangle by the mouse coordinates
         *
         * @param   startX
         * @param   startY
         * @param   endX
         * @param   endY
         * @returns {*}
         */
        calculateRectPos: function(startX, startY, endX, endY) {

            var width = endX - startX;
            var height = endY - startY;
            var posX = startX;
            var posY = startY;

            if (width < 0) {
                width = Math.abs(width);
                posX -= width;
            }

            if (height < 0) {
                height = Math.abs(height);
                posY -= height;
            }

            return {
                left: posX,
                top: posY,
                width: width,
                height: height
            };
        }
    }
);

$(function() {
    var paper = new Paper('#canvas', {});
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.rect {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid rgba(199, 25, 9, 0.64);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//canjs.com/release/1.1.7/can.jquery.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```